# How do I change my grip in Arms?

Tags: arms

In the "Help" tab of Arms, you can look at the controls for several grips, so this has made me wonder how to change my grip. The game never tells you how to change the grip and in the tutorial, the grip is always the thumbs-up grip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is no setting for you to change this. The game automatically detects the way you're holding the controller and changes the control scheme (grip) on its own. From [this thread trying to figure out the same thing](https://www.reddit.com/r/ARMS/comments/6j43ld/how_tf_do_you_change_control_method/):

> There is no setting to switch controls. Hold the joycons in whatever method you want and the game will automatically detect your method, using that scheme. For the controller grip style to be detected the joycons must be inline with each other, so it's best to use them with the grip rather than separately.
>
> It's all position based. If you put them in the included grip or hold them in that position before a match it'll switch to button controls. Or if you're playing 2 player a joycon per person you just pair 2 controllers and it'll automatically be button mode.